# How to reload / recompile / refresh directive in AngularJs?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-module

I have installed the [malhar-angular-dashboard](https://github.com/DataTorrent/malhar-angular-dashboard) module for the purpose of using widgets. After I configure my **options** the **dashboard-layouts** directive works fine and is displaying my widgets in the view. If I change the **options** in my controller after the directive has compiled I get this error:

> Widget fromTimeout is not found. undefined

**HTML**

---

```
 <div ng-controller="widgetCtrl">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12" style="background:#B8B7C9;">
      <div ng-if="layoutOptions"
           dashboard-layouts="layoutOptions"
           class="dashboard-container"
           template-url="views/dashboards/widget-area/customDashboardLayout.tmpl.html">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**Chose widget - button**

```
 <div class="btn-group" ng-if="!options.widgetButtons">
        <span class="dropdown" on-toggle="toggled(open)">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <span class="fa fa-bars"></span> Chose widget
          </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li ng-repeat="widget in layoutOptions.widgetDefinitions"> <!-- initial was : widget in widgetDefs -->
              <a href="#" ng-click="addWidgetInternal($event, widget);" class="dropdown-toggle"><span class="label label-primary">{{widget.name}}</span></a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </span>
</div>
```

**JavaScript Controller**

---

```
// layout with explicit save
$scope.layoutOptions = { 
        storageId: 'demo-layouts-explicit-save',
        storage: localStorage,
        storageHash: 'fs4df4d51',
        widgetDefinitions: $scope.myWidgets, // to be changed
        layoutDefinitions:widgetDefs.REQUEST_ATTRIBUTES.layouts, // to be changed
        defaultWidgets: [], 
        explicitSave: true,
        defaultLayouts: [
          {title: 'Layout 1', active: true, defaultWidgets: []}
        ]
      };

 $scope.newChanges = function(){
     $scope.layoutOptions = { 
        storageId: 'demo-layouts-explicit-save',
        storage: localStorage,
        storageHash: 'fs4df4d51',
        widgetDefinitions:[{name:"fromTimeout"}], //changed
        layoutDefinitions:[],                     //changed
        defaultWidgets: [], 
        explicitSave: true,
        defaultLayouts: [
          {title: 'Layout 1', active: true, defaultWidgets: []}
        ]
      };
 };
```

**Running the application**

---

1. First load (loading **layoutOptions**)

   [image: works]
2. After calling **newChanges()** function

   [image]

**Conclusion**

---

When I trigger the click event from **Chose widget** the **addWidgetInternal($event, widget)** is executed witch is leading me to this problem in the **dashboard-layout** directive code:

```
 scope.widgetDefs = new WidgetDefCollection(scope.options.widgetDefinitions);
  scope.addWidget = function (widgetToInstantiate, doNotSave) {

      if (typeof widgetToInstantiate === 'string') {
        widgetToInstantiate = {
          name: widgetToInstantiate
        };
      }

      var defaultWidgetDefinition = scope.widgetDefs.getByName(widgetToInstantiate.name); // is undefined
      if (!defaultWidgetDefinition) {
        throw 'Widget ' + widgetToInstantiate.name + ' is not found.';
      }

      // Determine the title for the new widget
      var title;
      if (!widgetToInstantiate.title && !defaultWidgetDefinition.title) {
        widgetToInstantiate.title = 'Widget ' + count++;
      }

      // Instantiation
      var widget = new WidgetModel(defaultWidgetDefinition, widgetToInstantiate);

      // Add to the widgets array
      scope.widgets.push(widget);
      if (!doNotSave) {
        scope.saveDashboard();
      }

      return widget;
    };
```

**I guess I need to recompile the directive in order to have access to my new changes I made from my controller. Any advice ?**

Comment: Are you using the `WidgetDataModel` to configure your widgetDefinitions ? I found that creating a subclass of that is very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not using the `layout-dashboard` directive, but I'm using the `dashboard` and `widget` directives. I've also struggled with this for a while regarding the use of the Kendo UI library, and found a hack to force a widget recompile.

It started when I discovered the scope.compileTemplate() function call in the widget directive code.

In my case, I searched for the Kendo grid class .k-grid, and found this method on the angular scope object: `$angular_scope.compileTemplate();`

So in my refresh code, I first look for any Kendo grid in the DOM (another hack):

```
   var grids = $(angular.element(document.getElementById('dash'))).find('.k-grid');
```

I then use _.each() to iterate the DOM elements:

```
  _.each(grids, function (elem) {
         var grid = $(elem).parent().find('.k-grid').data('kendoGrid');  
         // add'l code omitted...
         if (grid) {                    
             grid.$angular_scope.compileTemplate();          // *** COMPILE TEMPLATE ***
          }
    });
```

It's not very elegant, but it does recompile my HTML code when I'm dynamically swapping out the templateURL property of the widgets definition.

good luck,
Bob

Comment: pleasure. I hope it's useful.